# How to render text in a web browser while preserving line breaks?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

When I click on "View More" button it shows whole data in a dialogue box.

This is my **clientCertificate.config.js** file.

Here "DOO" is the string data I want to show (it's formatted). I am passing it in **ViewMore.js**.

```
{
        title: "Discription of Operations",
        key: "DOO",
        align: "left",
        fieldName: "DOO",
        custom: (row) => {
            let DOO = row && row?.standardWording || "" + row?.wosWording || "" + row?.alternateEmployerWording || "" + row?.customWording || "" + row?.projectInfoWording || "";
            if (DOO) {
                return (
                    <>
                        <span dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: truncate(DOO, { "length": 60 }) }}></span>
                        {DOO.length > 60 && <ViewMoreInfo data={DOO} title="Discription of Operations" />}
                    </>
                )
            } else {
                return <></>
            }
        }
    }
```

This is my function in **ViewMoreInfo.js** file. (It shows the data in the browser).

```
  const viewMoreContent = () => {
    console.log("Data: ", data) // data (it's formatted)
    return (
        <Box>
          <>
            <Typography align="left" className={classes.typography} gutterBottom >
              {data}
            </Typography>
          </>
        </Box>
    );
  };
```

The data is formatted in console like :-

> Coverage provided for all leased employees but not subcontractors
> of:
>
> Developer Test 18 DBA DeveloperTest
>
> Client Effective: 07/03/2023.

But it is not formatted in the browser, it's all in one line, like:-

> Coverage provided for all leased employees but not subcontractors of:
> Developer Test 18 DBA DeveloperTest Client Effective: 07/03/2023

Please Help! How do I format {data}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To format the data and preserve line breaks in the browser, you can use the white-space CSS property with the value pre-wrap on the element that displays the data. This will ensure that the line breaks in the data string are respected and displayed correctly in the browser.
You can update the viewMoreContent to include the necessary CSS. Something like  this

```js
  return (
    <Box>
      <Typography align="left" className={classes.typography} gutterBottom style={{ whiteSpace: 'pre-wrap' }}>
        {data}
      </Typography>
    </Box>
  );
```